# F#: How to examine content in a n-tuple and return true or false?

Tags: f#, f#-data

Consider this F# code:

```
let isSalary employee =
    let (fName,lName,Occupation,Department,SalaryType,
         HoursPerWeek, AnnualSalary, HourlyWage
        ) = employee
    SalaryType = "Salary"
    if(employee.SalaryType = SalaryType) then 
     true
    else 
     false
```

Im getting errors in here, any fixes to it?

Comment: Hi @dr_hakase, Welcome to StackOverFlow! Could you please elaborate on your problem, and post the error you facing with your code? You can also be helped by the following tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First things first, please post error messages and a much more specific question. Thanks! But luckily, I can about deduce the error messages from this problem.

Next, if you want to mutate SalaryType after you've deconstructed your `employee` 8-tuple, you should write using the `mutable` keyword:

`let mutable (fName, lName, Occupation, Department, SalaryType, 
              HoursPerWeek, AnnualSalary, HourlyWage) = employee`

But you shouldn't. This is explained further below.

Next problem: there is no dot notation (no `tuple.member`) for accessing members of a tuple. It's only possible through deconstruction. So you can't `employee.SalaryType`.

Here's what looks to be the crux of the problem, and it's a mistake I made many times when I was learning functional programming, and it's a difficult paradigm shift to adapt to. You should **not be attempting to mutate data**, or in this case, variables. Variables, or values as they are called in F#, shouldn't change, as a broad rule. Functions should be pure.

What this means is that any parameters you pass into a function should not change after leaving the function. The parameter `employee` should be the same after you return to the calling scope.

There's a few syntactical errors you've made that make it pretty much impossible for me to deduce what you're trying to do in the first place. Please include this in the question.

Also, one last nitpick. As you know, the last expression in an F# function is it's return value. Instead of using an if statement, just return the condition you're testing, like this:

`let ...
     ...
     employee.SalaryType = SalaryType` <- but remember, you can't use dot notation on tuples; this is just an example

Please read more on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/